# Both ctrl keys not working

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

I've recently got Win 8.1 Pro and a new keyboard and mouse(*Slimstar c110*). The keyboard worked but suddenly  both of my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys aren't working.

I tried doing tests and doing shortcuts but they aren't working, I'm almost 100% sure the keys themselves  aren't broken.

Are there any options that could have disabled my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys?

Comment: Can you elaborate about those `tests` you did?

Comment: I literally downloaded a program that lets you click a key and it shows the key you pressed on screen, I also tried doing some simple stuff like ctrl+c ctrl+p

Comment: If neither control keys are working anymore, then it means windows somehow registers that a control key is being pressed. This is known as a stuck key. This can happen if you hold a key while switching to or terminating a process. If you press that very same ctrl key again, it should resolve your issue. If you use a program to remotely connect to this computer, and you hold ctrl while disconnecting, the key may get stuck as well. It can also be that a shift or alt is being stuck. In any case, a reboot should solve your issue. Did you attempt a reboot?

Comment: Nothing I restared my pc and nothing happend

Comment: Try using a linux live CD and see if your control keys would work or not.

Comment: Did the `ctrl` key ever work? You mention the keyboard is new, don't exclude the possibility of a manuf. defect. That being said, there is a definitive way of diagnosing between hardware or software. Try booting to a linux live CD (or any other 3rd party O.S.), like mentioned above. ^^^ "Almost 100% certain" isn't very certain at all is it? Also, there's no point testing the keyboard using the same software if the issue is with the software itself

Comment: Check if ctrl key works over **On screen keyboard**

Comment: Try uninstalling all keyboards from *Device Manager*, plug it in and let windows install the drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for months, both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys and back arrow key did not work.

I had to reinstall Google Chrome, all keys then started working again.
This was possibly by accident or a related Chrome issue.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd> to fix.

I am not sure why this happens, but I was also not able to use both the Ctrl keys and this worked for me. Please find below the related thread.

http://ccm.net/forum/affich-28177-control-keys-not-working-on-laptop

Answer (score 1):

Did the `ctrl` key ever work? You mention the keyboard is new, don't exclude the possibility of a manuf. defect.

That being said, there is a definitive way of diagnosing between hardware or software. Try booting to a linux live CD (or any other 3rd party O.S.), like mentioned in the comments. Here's a list of free software that will allow you to make the diagnosis. [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download), [DamnSmallLinux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/download.html), [Comodo Live](https://www.comodo.com/business-security/network-protection/rescue-disk.php), [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/), [Ultimate BootCD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)

"Almost 100% sure" isn't very certain at all is it? Also, there's no point testing the keyboard using software if the issue is with the same software it question.

Answer (score 0):

I i cleaned inside of my keyboard with a soft napkin and vacuumcleaner incredibly control keys worked  before cleaning both ctrl keys wasn't working.